# Calculating the distribution, expected value and variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have no idea how to solve the following problem.
Could someone give me some pointers on how the solve the following problem?

> Choose a random country. Taken $n$ persons from this country.
>
> Define random variable $X$ as the number of persons $(\leq n)$ that claim to have a specific disease.
>   Define $q$ as the percentage of people in the country with this specific disease, then r.v. $Q$ varies from country to country. Assume $Q \stackrel{d}{=} U[0,1]$.
>
> a) How is $X|Q=q$ distributed?
>
> b) calculate $E[X]$ and Var$[X]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

a) $(X|Q=q)$ is the sum of $n$ variables taking value $1$ with probability $q$ and $0$ otherwise.

b) Start with the computation on the variance conditionally to the value of $Q$.